# Toggle property of different states

Tags: reactjs

Small question here. 
I have 3 div classes that contain images that I want to toggle the state property for each picture every time a user presses on one of the images (div actually). 
The states are as follows:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      img_1: 0,
      img_2: 0,
      img_3: 0
    };
  }
```

And I want to have a single handle function that can toggle for all the different images that I have. 
Here is the div code (its the same for every image):

```
<div className="pics" onClick={(e) => this.handlePic(e)}>
  <h2>First picture</h2>
  <img alt="" src={pic1} className="tier2"/>
</div>
```

And The handle function is empty at the moment, because I have no idea how to pass into it the name of `this.state.img_1`. The value of course should toggle between 0 and 1, but I want to be able to use a single function for the toggle of all 3 images.
I am not sure if my question makes a lot of sense, please let me know if you want me to explain a little bit more of my situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 different `div`, in each of your dives define an `onClick={()=>this.myhandle(nameofpic)}` (you can hardcode nameofpic here,for example in each div put a name like "img1","img2" ... instead of nameofpic)
Then in your `myhandle()` put your ifs ,like this :

```
myhandle(nameofpic){
if(nameofpic==="img_1")
 {this.setState({img_1:"valuechange"})
  } 
if(nameofpic==="img_2")
 {this.setState({img_2:"valuechange"})
 }
if(nameofpic==="img_3")
 {this.setState({img_3:"valuechange"})
 }}
```

I hope you get the idea and works for you

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate component for Image, which will handle it's own state. This way you can manage any number of Images not just 3.

```
function Image({url}) {
const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(false);

const toggleState = () => {
setOverlay(!overlay)
}

return <img src={url} alt={url} onClick={toggleState} />
}
```

Here `overlay` can be anything.

Now you can use this component any number of time and it will have it's own state management.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use this part of code, but something that I am having hard time understanding is how can I set the 'overlay' to anything that I want? I have 3 different states, each state for each picture. How can I update the ```overlay``` to work for all possible states that I have?

Comment: By setting `overlay` to anything I mean. You can your own state variable instead of `overlay`. It's just a state name. Since the code example above uses `React Hooks`, i think you can go though https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-started-with-react-hooks-f0b5c1e3e0e7, to understand hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you are not using hooks then,

In render method(passing static string in parameter for handler method):

```
<div className="pics" onClick={e => this.handlePic('img1')}>
    <h2>First picture</h2>
    <img alt="" src={pic1} className="tier2" />
</div>
```

Your handler(Setting dynamic key):

```
handlePic = key => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ [key]: !prevState[key] })); // This will toggle 0 or 1 simultaneously.
};
```